# Protect individual file with nginx / Tomcat7 and Java app

Tags: java, excel, nginx, tomcat7

I am running NGINX on an ubuntu server and have a Java app (ZK Sheets).  I am running tomcat7 and would like to protect a specific file:

`domain.com:8080/zssapp/#demo.xls`  is a file that I would like to protect.

That URL takes me to the spreadsheet and opens `demo.xls`

I understand `basic_auth` but figure that only applies to directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic_auth can be used in any location block. And directive Location can be defined by a file uri too. e.g.

```
location /zssapp/demo.xls {
  basic_auth ....;
}
```

Your case won't work because the part after "#" is a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)  of a uri and the client (e.g. browser) won't sent this part to the server at all.

e.g. when we use curl to access http://localhost:8080/zssapp/#demo.xls

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8080/zssapp/#demo.xls

> GET /zssapp/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
```

We can see only /zssapp/ as a uri data sent to the server.